# not understanding how a Linkedlist node pointer points to other nodes?

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public class ListNode {
  int val;
  ListNode next;
  ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```

So given a defination of a listnode class above. If I do

```
ListNode node1 = new ListNode(-1);
```

then

```
ListNode node2 = node1;
```

Does that mean node 2 points to node1 or node1 now has a pointer to node2.

and if I do 
`ListNode node3 = new ListNode(-7); then
node2.next = node3;`

Does that mean we now have a node1->node2->node3 pointing this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example

```
ListNode node1 = new ListNode(-1);
ListNode node2 = node1;
```

`node1` and `node2` are now pointing to the same `ListNode` object

```
System.out.println(node1.equals(node2));
```

Will print `true` without overriding `equals()`.

When you do

```
ListNode node3 = new ListNode(-7);
node2.next = node3;
```

You are assigning `node3` to the `next` class member of `node2`, and therefor to `node1`'s one `next` as well

```
System.out.println(node1.next.equals(node2.next)); // true
System.out.println("node1: " + node1.next.val + " node2: " + node2.next.val); // node1: -7 node2: -7
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that when you write `ListNode node1 = new ListNode(-1)` and then `ListNode node2 = node1`, both 'node1' and 'node2' and pointing to the 'new ListNode(-1)' *object*. Thus if you change 'node1' or 'node2', it will be changing the pointer to something else.

Now once you do

```
ListNode node3 = new ListNode(-7);
ListNode node2 = node1;
```

you're `node2` is still pointing to the `new ListNode(-1)` object, thus you'll end up with -1 -> -7. For the pointers, you'll have `node1 -> ListNode(-1)`, `node2 -> ListNode(-1)`, and `node3 -> ListNode(-7)`.